# GMap ajax "pointSelect" event doesn't work after validation

Tags: java, ajax, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I have awkward problem. Primefaces' GMap component works as I expected until... I return a message to  component after validating data on backing bean. After that map does not react on ajax's "pointSelect" event. It can be moved, zoomed-in, etc, but I cannot go into my  code that's responsible for adding markers. Here's my code:

Primefaces

```
<p:outputLabel for="add_marker" value="Punkt:" />
        <p:outputPanel id="add_marker" style="text-align:center;">
        <p:gmap id="add_gmap" widgetVar="addMap"
                center="#{addSpotController.sampleSpot.latitude}, #{addSpotController.sampleSpot.longitude}" zoom="15"
                model="#{addSpotController.model}" type="HYBRID" style="width:600px;height:400px" streetView="true">
            <p:ajax event="pointSelect" listener="#{addSpotController.addMarker}"
                    update=":#{p:component('add_gmap')}, :#{p:component('add_msgs')},
                        :#{p:component('basicDT')},:#{p:component('mfDT')}" />
        </p:gmap>
</p:outputPanel>    

<p:commandButton id="add_confirm" value="Dodaj" actionListener="#{addSpotController.addSpot}"
        update=":#{p:component('add_msgs')},  :#{p:component('addForm')}, :#{p:component('addInfoTitle')}, :#{p:component('add_gmap')}" 
            oncomplete="PF('addInfo').show()">
</p:commandButton>
```

BackingBean

```
public void addMarker(PointSelectEvent pse) {
    FacesMessage message;
    if (title == null || title.isEmpty()) {
        message = new FacesMessage("Brak tytułu", "Najpierw wprowadź tytuł.");
    } else {
        if (!model.getMarkers().isEmpty()) {
            model.getMarkers().clear();
        }
        Marker marker = new Marker(pse.getLatLng(), title);
        model.addOverlay(marker);
        LatLng latLng = marker.getLatlng();
        sampleSpot.setLatitude(latLng.getLat());
        sampleSpot.setLongitude(latLng.getLng());
        message = new FacesMessage("Dodano punkt:", title);
    }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

public void addSpot() {
        if (isDataValid()) {
            Marker marker = model.getMarkers().get(0);
            savedID = spotService.addSpot(new UserBean(), marker, newSpotReceiverType, receiversList);

            sampleSpot = spotService.getSampleSpot();

            browseController.refreshSpotList();
            modifyController.refreshSpotList();

            clearForms();
            setExportUrl();
        } else {
            for(String error: errors ) {
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Błędne dane", error);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
            }
            errors.clear();
        }
}
```

Why do ajax stops retrieving pointSelect events?